# Wrong value with a function that returns a double (libffi)

Tags: c, pointers, double, libffi

It seems that a function returning a double data type, from libffi, is not correctly casted when the function returns its value, here is the code I used:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ffi.h>
#include <math.h>  // The make call the function `cos` by the FFI.

int main()
{
  ffi_cif cif;
  ffi_type *args[1];
  void *values[1];
  ffi_arg rc;

  args[0] = &ffi_type_double;

  void *ptr = malloc(sizeof(double));
  *((double *)ptr) = 3.0;
  values[0] = ptr;

  if (ffi_prep_cif(&cif, FFI_DEFAULT_ABI, 1, &ffi_type_double, args) == FFI_OK)
      ffi_call(&cif, cos, &rc, values);

  printf("%f\n", (double)rc);

  return 0;
}
```

The result is as follows: `13830464316077631000.000000`.

The `ffi_arg` type is an alias for `unsigned long long`. The documentation states that the argument of type `ffi_arg` passed to the `ffi_call` function, is used to store data if it is smaller than `sizeof(ffi_arg)`, otherwise it is a pointer to the data in memory:

> *rvalue* must point to storage that is `sizeof(ffi_arg)` or larger for
>   non-floating point types. For smaller-sized return value types, the
>   `ffi_arg` or `ffi_sarg` integral type must be used to hold the return
>   value.

(https://manpages.debian.org/testing/libffi-dev/ffi_call.3.en.html)

So I tried it with a pointer dereference:

```
void* rc;
// The code to call the function and initialize the CIF...
double my_value = *(double *)((void *)rc);
```

Which crashed the program.

How am I supposed to access the value stored using the `rc` variable?

**EDIT 1**

The command line used to compile the program:

```
gcc source.c -lffi -o source
```

There are no errors or warnings at compile time.

**EDIT 2**

After adding the `-Wall' build option, I get:

```
warning: passing argument 2 of 'ffi_call' from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
ffi_call(&cif, cos, &rc, values);
               ^~~
```

This warning seems to be ignored in the [libffi example](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/doc/libffi-dev/html/Simple-Example.html). The example given works very well for me (with this warning).

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include the exact command line(s) used to compile your code.  Were there any warnings when you compiled the code?

Comment: It's edited @jwdonahue.

Comment: Add -Wall and fix/report any warnings.

Comment: It's edited @jwdonahue.

Comment: How is cos defined in your environment?  Their example uses puts, not cos.

Comment: This is the `cos` function defined in `math.h`. The library I use the foreign function interface allow access to the `FFI_FN` macro, which runs in `((void (*)(void))f)`. The result doesn't change, it just removes the warning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is *simple*. The `ffi_arg` is not the type you're supposed to put your return value to. Instead, the 3rd argument is defined as a *pointer to void*, that should point to an object *that is suitably large* to contain the return value, and of proper alignment, and *of proper type*, or interpreted as such, thus:

```
double rv;
...
ffi_call(&cif, cos, &rv, values);
```

or

```
void *rv = malloc(sizeof (double));
...
ffi_call(&cif, cos, rv, values);
double value = *(double *)rv;
```

---

As for the warning, that happens because the libffi code is not strictly portable. A function pointer cannot be automatically converted to a `void *`. You can silence the warning with an explicit cast:

```
ffi_call(&cif, (void *)cos, rv, values);
```

At least it does not make it any more wrong than it already is.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT - 
According to the documentation

> FFI - 
>   rvalue must point to storage that is sizeof(ffi_arg) or larger for non-floating point types. For smaller-sized return value types, the ffi_arg or ffi_sarg integral type must be used to hold the return value.

The function definition for ffi_call is

```
void ffi_call(ffi_cif *cif, void (*fn)(void), void *rvalue, void **avalue);
```

Instead of passing a ffi_arg to the function you need to pass a void* which is allocated space of a double.

```
void* rc = malloc(sizeof(double));
ffi_call(&cif, cos, rc, values);
printf("%f\n", *(double *)rc);
```

This will lead to a correct answer without you making any assumption about the function being called.

Comment: This is a typing error for the file inclusion that I inserted by mistake when I copied my code, I corrected it in my question, however, as you point out, the error remains.

Comment: I use the version `9.3.0` of the MSYS2 gcc compiler on MinGW.

Comment: `ffi_arg` being a type alias for `unsigned long long`, a dynamic allocation does not seem appropriate. However, this does not affect the result. Moreover libffi allocates and assigns space and value itself.

Comment: Can you point me to the documentation which says that ffi_arg is an unsigned long long, because I can't seem to find that, it seems to me that it should only be used for integer types as indicated by "rvalue must point to storage that is sizeof(ffi_arg) or larger for non-floating point types. For smaller-sized return value types, the ffi_arg or ffi_sarg integral type must be used to hold the return value."

Comment: I misinterpreted your question, since you don't want to assume anything about the return value of the function you can't do ```double rc;``` but what you can do is ```void* rc = malloc(sizeof(double)); ```  ```ffi_call(&cif, cos, rc, values);``` ```printf("%f\n", *(double *)rc);``` according to the function signature and documentation you need to pass a pointer to a storage which can hold the value of the return double. I got the answer to be -0.989992 with these changes.

Comment: Oh, that's a good point! Your comment was posted at the same time as another answer, which gives this solution (and I can't mark a comment as "issue resolved", but consider it so). Thanks to you, and welcome to SO!